# Avatar is not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'd like to add avatar to the users and I did the steps but when I update the user I choose the photo but it isn't updated I don't know what is the problem
every other attributes are updated successfully.

```
edit.html.erb

    <%= form_for(current_user,:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :username%>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Fullname %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :Fullname%>
      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :company %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :company %>
      </div>



      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :age %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :age %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :like_number %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :like_number %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :dislike_number %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :dislike_number %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :user_points %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :user_points %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

users_controller

    def edit
      end

    def user_params
           params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :age,:company,:username, :Fullname, :email, :password, :gender, :like_number, :dislike_number, :user_points)
        end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if current_user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

users model

    #every user has an image (avatar)
        attr_accessor :avatar_file_name
        attr_accessor :avatar_content_type
        attr_accessor :avatar_file_size
        attr_accessor :avatar_updated_at
        #has_attached_file :avatar, 

     has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

migration

    class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Migration
      # save an image (avatar) of type attachment to user table in database  
    class AddAttachmentAvatarToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_attachment :users, :avatar
      end
    end 
    end


gemfile

    gem 'xpath', '~> 2.0.0'
    #to upload a photo use paperclip gem.
    #to use this gem you should download ImageMagick.
    #to download ImageMagick :
          # sudo apt-get update
          # sudo apt-get install imagemagick
    gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'

controller 
def show 
end

show.html.erb
<!--check if the user has a photo or not  -->
<!--if user hasn't a photo , display the defult photo -->
<!--if user has photo , display it -->

     <%if current_user.avatar.blank? %>
     <%if current_user.gender == 'Female'%>
      <img class="language-flag" src="/assets/girl.jpg" titile="Change Photo">
     <%else%>
      <img class="language-flag" src="/assets/boy.jpg" titile="Change Photo">
     <% end %>
     <%else%>
     <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:large) %>
     <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want the avatar to actually show up? I'm guessing in `user#show`? If so, can you post that code as well. I'm guessing you are saving/uploading things ok, but just not grabbing things from the database and actually sending them to the view.

Comment: I have edited the question and added show.html.erb and show in controller

Comment: Hmm...ok...views look good to me. Is imagemagick installed and working? Are files actually being stored in the path you specify (or default path) during upload?  What happens when you go into the rails console to check for avatars? So assuming your have uploaded an avatar to your first user, something like u = User.first.avatar

Comment: I can't find avatar in the scheme or when I use rails console to find users avatar there is no field with attr avatar @aspencer8111

Comment: Have your run your migrations? i.e. ```rake db:migrate``` ?

Comment: Yes I did and it succeeded